# How to detect social media giants Bots and refine the useragent in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, bots

I am trying to build the script that will capture the USER-AGENT of the users.That can easily be done using **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']**

example: Below are all the twitter Bots that detect by **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']**

I just simple post the link of php script on twitter and it detect the bots:
[image: here]

Here are the Bots thats Captured by **HTTP_USER_AGENT** of twitter network.

**1**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/52.0
```

**2**

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
```

**3**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/6.1; News; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)
```

**4**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; TrendsmapResolver/0.1)
```

**5 (Not sure its bot or Normal Agent)**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

**6**

```
Twitterbot/1.0
```

**7**

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5 (Applebot/0.1; +http://www.apple.com/go/applebot)
```

Now I want to **Refine/filter** the Bots name from the detected **HTTP_USER_AGENT**

**example:**

```
rv:1.9.1.2
Trident/4.0
(compatible; AhrefsBot/6.1; News; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)
(compatible; TrendsmapResolver/0.1)
Twitterbot/1.0
(Applebot/0.1; +http://www.apple.com/go/applebot)
```

What I have tried so far:

```
if (
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Twitterbot/1.0") !== false ||          
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Applebot/0.1") !== false
) {
    $file =fopen("crawl.txt","a");
    fwrite($file,"TW-bot detected.\n");
    echo "TW-bot detected.";
}
else {
     $file =fopen("crawl.txt","a");
    fwrite($file,"Nothing found.\n");
    echo "Nothing";
}
```

But somehow the above code is not working.let me know where I am getting wrong and  in the **crawl.txt** always shows **Nothing found**
let me know the proper/better/best way to detect bots or any direction or guidence is apprecheated.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that its easy to spot the bots which capture simple website previews, but the user-agents of bots which scrape for restricted content are a lot more difficult.

You'd have to do more than just parse the UA.  Interrogating the REMOTE_ADDR will be necessary also. You'd fire each request through something like http://ip-api.com to determine if its coming from a datacenter.  Be careful of users with proxies, they will trigger false positives.   You could go further and investigate the browser capabilities with Javascript, but be aware this is a difficult problem and its a constant arms-race between a providers detection tools and (usually) black-hat advertisers.